# Unable to connect CRM server in OptionSetImport software- getting an error (400) bad request

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using MS Window server 2008 and is trying to import loads of options(picklist) using OptionSet Import wizard. When setup a new connection and tried to connect to the CRM on the server itself I'm getting an error message below
[image]

Have got the organization name as well input with the configuration information when clicked on load button. But when clicked on connect button (Do you want to connect now to this server) there is no luck. I'm not able to identify where I'm going wrong.

Screenshot is below
[image]

Comment: long shot: Windows Identity Foundation is installed? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331

Comment: Can you verify that you can hit the SDK Endpoints in the browser on that machine using the ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Please delete Live Device ID in your current system

start->select your user-> Live Device ID
and delete the LiveDevice.XML file and try again.